# Flag to not require mandatory arguments in Argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program that accepts input file, input format, and output format as required arguments via argparse. However, I'd like to have "--test" as a flag, where it will run through all of my unit tests.

How do I set this to be a flag that can run without the required arguments? In the same way that a traditional -h flag does?

```py
def process_args():
    global args
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Convert quantum circuits into different environments")
    parser.add_argument("input_filename", help="input filename")
    parser.add_argument("input_format", help="input format of your script", choices=valid_program_types)
    parser.add_argument("output_format", help="output format of your script", choices=valid_program_types)
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output_filename", help="set output filename, without file extension "
                                                        "(default: convertqc_result.<filetype>")
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", help="enable debug mode", action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Are you trying to have like multiple actions with one `cli` ? For example: 
`myprogram runtests` `myprogram input_filename input_format ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

`-h` works by triggering a specific action of type `_HelpAction`, as if defined by something like

```
parser.add_argument('-h', action='help')
```

This action calls (eventually) `sys.exit`, and so bypasses the rest of the parsing algorithm, rendering the issue of required arguments moot.

You can define your own custom action `TestAction` by subclassing `Action` (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action for details), then defining `--test` with

```
class TestAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        """ Run your tests and exit the script here """

parser.add_argument("--test", action=TestAction)
```

---

Alternatively, define separate subcommands `test` and `run`, so that only the `run` subcommand has required arguments, and the `test` subcommand simply runs your tests and exists.

---

However, the best thing to do is to decouple running your unit tests from running your script. There's no reason to even *deploy* your unit tests in an environment where you expect to run your script. Use a separate test runner script (or something like `nosetests`) to run your tests without running your script itself.